# no-cache doesn't work with require.js

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, requirejs, browser-cache

I have below in my `<head>`

The .css is not cached and new one loaded in each refresh. But since I use **Backbone.js** and **Require.js**, the modules are still cached. I don't use optimizer yet. I uploaded the files to Apache server and just run html/js straight.

How can I eliminate caching here? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this before you import require.js.

```
        var require = {
            waitSeconds: 1,
            urlArgs : "bust="+new Date().getTime()
        };
```

The urlArgs put a timestamp after everything it fetches and break require.js cache.

as seen [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can turn off cache per website if Firebug is running and cache is off within Firebug under Net tab.